# KineticJS version 5.1 Drawing a line with mouse

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am updating my application from KineticJS 4.3.3 to 5.1, I used the following to draw a line using the mouse.
In 4.3.3 I used

```
stage.getMousePosition();
```

It works please see http://jsfiddle.net/hnabih/rrxjdbaq/1/

Since 5.1 does not support getMousePosition, I changed it to:

```
stage.getPointerPosition();
```

I also changed:

```
line.getPoints() to line.points()
```

I can draw lines, but the location is wrong.  Please see http://jsfiddle.net/hnabih/vofsst14/.
Would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change all `points` usage API.
In KineticJS v5 `points` is array of numbers [x1, y1, x2, y2, ...].

So instead of

```
points[1].x = bla;
```

You have to write

```
points[2] = bla;
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed it be still don't get the right line position.

Comment: Show changed jsfiddle.